# Install these "win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api"

Tags: 16.04, python3, anaconda

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import win32api
```

How can I install above modules for Python 3 in Ubuntu 16.04?
My OS is 64 bit.

Comment: Tried with pip?

Comment: yes @Videonauth. I'm getting this error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pfb1wxox/win32gui/
`

Comment: yes it asks for winreg module, which might be in another package maybe?

Comment: yes @Videonauth. `        import winreg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
`

Comment: You can't. They are Python interfaces for Windows functions. Linux does not have these functions. You can perhaps run python in wine, but ymmv.

Comment: How @vidarlo? Any instruction....